# crossDomain heartbeat cant parse jsonp data with jquery

Tags: jquery, json, security, same-origin-policy, heartbeat

I embbeding my module, an asp.net project, in a "portal", the portal generate an iframe to my url, i know its a shit but i dont made it.
To avoid session in main "portal" end while user iterating with my web project the portal owner told me to start an heartbeat by javascript from my application to portal.
Everyone know keep session in this way is insecure but 'portal' there is then i havent nothing to do.
The real problem is that i cant do cross-domain requests from my application to portal because [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) lock it, i found a solution using jquery but it require [heartbeat listener] deal with json.
The official jsonp site [here](http://json-p.org/).
Someone can help me?
there is my script:

```
function startHeartbeat() 
{
    var interval = 9513575;
    window.setInterval(
         function () {
             $.ajax({
                 type: "GET",
                 cache: false,
                 async: true,
                 crossDomain: true,
                 url: "http://www.theportalurl.com",
                 dataType: 'JSONP',
                 complete:function(jqXHR, textStatus){                    
                     alert("Complete");
                 },
                 success:function(json){                    
                     alert("Success");
                 },
                 error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                     alert("Error:" + textStatus + ", detail:" + errorThrown);
                 },
            });

         }
     , interval
     );
}
```

after @rook give me help i reach this:

```
function startHeartbeat(pgn) 
{
    $("body").append("<img id='heartbeat' style='width:1px; height:1px' name='heartbeat' src='http://www."+Math.random()+".org'/>");
    var interval = 350000;
    window.setInterval(
         function () {
            var rnd = Math.random();
            var url = "https://www.theportal.com/refreshsession.aspx?pgn="+pgn+"&rndv="+rnd;
            $("#heartbeat").attr("src", url);
         }
     , interval
     );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is a clear violation of the same origin policy for JavaScript.  A good solution is that the portal owner can set this http header element for the page (and **only** the page) that you want to fetch with an XHR.

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://foo.example`

source: [http access control](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control)

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer but i cant change portal, cant change code, cant change config, maybe i can put my application under the same root http://www.theportalurl.com/myapplicationhere.

Comment: @newway  if its on the same domain then you shouldn't have a problem,  another solutions is a "cross domain proxy".

Comment: Thanks a lot. It isnt in the same domain but i will ask for it to my admin, im not free to put hands on the server and dont want it too ;) then put in the same domain become the last unique possibility.

Comment: @newway another thing,  if you aren't worried about getting a response you can just write an invisible <img> tag to the page which will fire off a get request.  This is commonly used in XSRF/CSRF exploits.

Comment: Thanks again. I can target some image in portal home. Cant change portal. Are you telling about it: http://www.intelliproject.net/articles/showArticle/index/js_session_expired